# How to parse a string into a list in Mirth Connect?

Tags: mirth

I use Mirth Connect version 3.7,

I need to parse a global variable `globalVariable` defined in global settings and use it's value in one of destination filters.

This variable contains comma-separated values.

```
globalVariable= 'A,B,C'
```

I use that variable in a Javascript code inside a destination filter.

```js
var someValue = 'B';
var arr = $('globalVariable');
if (arr && arr.split(',').includes(someValue)) {
  return  true;
}
return false;
```

But somehow Mirth-Connect cannot transform my code correctly. It complaints about that type not having `include()` method. 
What am I doing wrong here? I expected after `split()` to have a Javascript array.

Comment: `$('globalVariable')` will probably select the element itself instead of the value of the element. Just add like .value or .val() or whatever the correct syntax is to extract the actual content/value/innerText of whatever `globalVariable` is.

Comment: It works correctly up to the `split()` part. I get an array after that function. But it seems not to know the `includes()` function.

Comment: What browser are you using? `.includes()` is chrome 47+, edge 14+, ff43+ and not supported at all  on IE.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=includes

Comment: @Shilly, it's an integration server, not a browser.

Comment: Try replacing the `.includes()` with the `.reduce()` that does the same thing and should be supported by everything. Mirth will still need some kind of javascript parser that supports `.includes()`, just like the browser. If that doesn't even work, there's an issue with stuff we can't see.

Comment: Just like the browsers, `Array.prototype.includes()` wasn't originally [part of Javascript](https://i.imgur.com/Icglxs6.png) when using Node and generally most other Javascript engines. Node < 6 (or Node 5 without Harmony, e.g. E6 support), it won't work either. What's described is lack of support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla Rhino is the javascript engine that Mirth uses. It doesn't have Array.prototype.includes.

You can do this instead:

```
if (arr && arr.split(',').indexOf(someValue) > -1) {
  return  true;
}
return false;
```

Here's the Rhino javascript feature compatibility chart. To have access to the latest features you need to be running mirth 3.7+ in "ES6" mode. https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html

Comment: @gitrust If you can't get a newer version of Rhino, there are ES6 shim/polyfill libraries that can help.

Comment: Many ways to accomplish the same thing. `new java.util.HashSet(arr.split(',')).contains(someValue)` would work, too. Using Array.prototype.indexOf is basically the same as includes, though, with -1 being false and any index 0 or greater being true.

Comment: And I would not recommend using a version of rhino other than the one that shipped with your mirth version.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing me to the right direction. Though  `java.util.HashSet` didn't work for me. I try to use only the board-resources of Mirth. So I will stick to suggestion of @agermano in the answer.